# How to change font and background for pageMessage summary

Tags: visualforce

How to make the salesforce warning  in the pic to be red background and white font or red bold font?

Here is the VF page code

```
<apex:page standardController="Community_Yearly_Plan__c" extensions="vf_CommunityPlanGoalPSetting_Cntrlr" cache="false">

    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="pbsCon" >
                <apex:outputPanel id="panelCon">
                    <div id="loading-curtain-div"/>

                    <apex:pageBlockTable id="pbtCon" value="{!listGoalsCurrYear}" var="cpgs">
                        <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="cnt"/>   
                        <apex:column headervalue="Action">
                            <apex:commandlink value="Remove" onclick="return validateFunction();" action="{!removeRecord}" immediate="true">
                                <!-- Pass the row number to the controller so that we know which row to remove -->
                                <apex:param name="index" value="{!cnt}"/>
                            </apex:commandlink> 
                            <apex:variable var="cnt" value="{!cnt+1}"/>  
                        </apex:column>  

<!--                        <apex:column value="{!cpgs.Year__c}" />                        
-->                        
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Year</apex:facet>                             
                            <apex:inputField id="hdr" value="{!cpgs.Year__c}" rendered="True" />
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Funding Type</apex:facet>                             
                            <apex:inputField id="ft" value="{!cpgs.Funding_Type__c}" rendered="True" />
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Description</apex:facet>                                                         
                            <apex:inputField id="ccp" value="{!cpgs.Core_Current_Participation__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs.Funding_Type__c!='Elective' && cpgs.Funding_Type__c!='Other','True','False')}" />
                            <apex:inputField id="ftd" value="{!cpgs.Funding_Type_Description__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs.Funding_Type__c='Elective' || cpgs.Funding_Type__c='Other','True','False')}" />                            

                        </apex:column>   
<!--                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Funding Description</apex:facet>                                                         
                            <apex:inputField id="fd" value="{!cpgs.Funding_Description__c}" rendered="True" />
                        </apex:column>   
-->
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Goal Amount</apex:facet>                                                         
                            <apex:inputField id="ga" value="{!cpgs.Goal_Amount__c}" rendered="True" />
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Goal Amount Comments</apex:facet>                            
                            <apex:inputField id="gac" value="{!cpgs.Goal_Amount_Comments__c}" rendered="True" />
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Funding Amount</apex:facet>                                                         
                            <apex:inputField id="fa" value="{!cpgs.Funding_Amount__c}" rendered="True"  />
                        </apex:column>   

                    </apex:pageBlockTable>

                    <apex:commandButton style="align:center;" action="{!AddRow}" value="Add Funding/Goal" reRender="pbsCon" />
                    <apex:commandButton style="align:center;" action="{!SaveRecords}" value="Save/Update" reRender="pbsCon" />                    

                    <apex:pageMessage summary="PLEASE NOTE: Any changes including adding or deleting rows only go into effect when the 'Save/Update' button is clicked. Otherwise changes are lost when one leaves or refreshes the page." severity="warning" strength="3" />

                    <apex:pageMessages rendered="{!showMsg}" />


                </apex:outputPanel>

                <apex:outputPanel id="panelCon2">
                    <div id="loading-curtain-div"/>

                    <apex:pageBlockTable id="pbtCon2" value="{!listGoalsPrevYears}" var="cpgs2">

                        <apex:column value="{!cpgs2.Year__c}" />                        
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Funding Type</apex:facet>                            
                            <apex:outputField value="{!cpgs2.Funding_Type__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs2.EditableOrReadOnly__c!='True','True','False')}" />                            

                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Core Current Participation</apex:facet>                                                         
                            <apex:outputField value="{!cpgs2.Core_Current_Participation__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs2.EditableOrReadOnly__c!='True','True','False')}" />                            
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Funding Amount</apex:facet>                                                                                     
                            <apex:outputField value="{!cpgs2.Funding_Amount__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs2.EditableOrReadOnly__c!='True','True','False')}" />                            
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Funding Description</apex:facet>                                                                                     
                            <apex:outputField value="{!cpgs2.Funding_Description__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs2.EditableOrReadOnly__c!='True','True','False')}" />
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Goal Amount</apex:facet>                                                                                     
                            <apex:outputField value="{!cpgs2.Goal_Amount__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs2.EditableOrReadOnly__c!='True','True','False')}" />
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Goal Amount Comments</apex:facet>                                                        
                            <apex:outputField value="{!cpgs2.Goal_Amount_Comments__c}" rendered="{!IF(cpgs2.EditableOrReadOnly__c!='True','True','False')}" />
                        </apex:column>   

                    </apex:pageBlockTable>

                </apex:outputPanel>                
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
    <script>    

    function validateFunction()
    {

        var r = confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this row?');
        if (r == true) 
        {
            return true
        } else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    </script>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add Warning message using `apex:pageMessage` this will render in HTML like this

```
<div class="message warningM2" role="alert">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="messageTable" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">
            <tbody><tr valign="top">
                <td>
                    <img alt="warning" class="msgIcon" src="/s.gif" title="warning">
                </td>
                <td class="messageCell"><div id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id3:j_id5" class="messageText"><span id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id3:j_id6">
                                <h4></h4></span>PLEASE NOTE: Any changes including adding or deleting rows only go into effect when the 'Save/Update' button is clicked. Otherwise changes are lost when one leaves or refreshes the page.<br></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </div>
```

So add these CSS class

```
.message {
    background-color: #c00; // change background color here
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    color: #000;
    padding: 6px 8px 6px 6px;
    margin: 4px 20px;
    color: white;
}
.message .messageText {
    margin-left: 8px;
    color: white; //change fonnt color here
}
```

And you will get output like
[image]